# How to find Integrating factor of this equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Equation 
$$
    (x^2 e^{-y/x} + y^2 ) dx -xy dy =0
$$
**Not Exact**

**Q)** Further solution is possible ? means Integrating factor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2e^{-y/x}+y^2=xy\frac{dy}{dx}$$
is a homogeneous differential equation, so the substitution $y=vx$ can make progress.
$$x^2e^{-v}+v^2x^2=vx^2\left(v+x\frac{dv}{dx}\right)$$
$$e^{-v}=vx\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dx}x=ve^vdv$$
$$\ln|x|=(v-1)e^v+C=\left(\frac yx-1\right)e^{y/x}+C$$